How to Keep IME Open When Using Buttons for Input in a Custom Japanese Virtual Keyboard in WPF?
I'm developing a .NET WPF application, and my client requires a custom Japanese input keyboard.
The input method is not through a physical keyboard but via UI buttons that input each character.
Here is my problem: when I use mouse to press a UI button, I want the IME (Input Method Editor) to appear with candidate options and dynamically change based on the button clicks, similar to keyboard input. However, every time I click a button, the IME closes, which disrupts the input context.
I tried handling input by restricting button events, but it didn't work.
How can I keep the IME open and maintain the input context when clicking buttons? Any suggestions or workarounds would be greatly appreciated.
Thank you!

Fix your virtual input by not allowing it to get activated. To do this handle the WM_MOUSEACTIVATE message by returning the appropriate MA_NOACTIVATE constant. How can I have a window that rejects activation but still receives pointer input? covers this in much more detail.

So, "IME" is basically a "screen writer"; and you are not able to do the same; using buttons and the appropriate font?  Isn't it all just (unicode) "characters"? (I've done virtual keyboards)
